# Book with reptiles and a hole in the sky that eats souls

Tags: story-identification, books

Years ago, I started reading a sci-fi/fantasy book that started with a bunch of people on some world dying in a war.

There was this big hole in the sky that was eating people's souls and a reptile guy was working for the king wearing robes.  I think everyone was a reptile but it could have just been the enemies.

They all get their souls eaten and then it goes to a different world where the main character is a young man.

He is having to help prepare because some duke or earl is coming through town. The duke or earl is actually his father.

That's all I can remember but it has been bugging me.

I think there was the word *sword* in the title but I don't know for sure.

Thanks!

Comment: What happen when someone's soul gets eaten? do they die? become an empty living shell, like a zombie?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This sounds like [Shadow of a Dark Queen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_of_a_Dark_Queen), the first book of the [Serpentwar Saga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Serpentwar_Saga), part of the Riftwar Cycle by Raymond E. Feist.

The prologue describes how a world of serpent people (Saaur) is destroyed by demons coming through a portal. Afterwards the story starts with Erik on the day the local baron visits his village. His mother indeed claims that the Baron is his father.

Comment: I've read the Serpantwar Saga twice, but this didn't spring to mind at all! Good job!

Comment: I found this in a google search yesterday but decided it didn't sound right. Dangit. Good find, though.